# Section is not displaying under header

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to solve my problem for a few hours but it doesn't seem too clear. I have a header image and a navigation bar. I need the nav bar to display under the header image, however it keeps displaying on top of it.

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

q, blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Fragment;
  src: url("../fonts/Fragmentcore.otf");
}
.site-nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid;
  background: #fff;
  width: 12%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.site-nav li {
  margin: 0.97em 0.8em 0 0.8em;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
.site-nav a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Fragment';
  font-weight: bold;
}
.site-nav li:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
.site-nav li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .site-nav {
    left: 85px;
    width: 19%;
  }
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: white;
  background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*@media screen and (min-width: $size-small){
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
  }*/
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  font-family: 'Fragment';
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 42px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header-container"></div>
    </header>

    <section id="content">
        <nav class="site-nav">
            <h1>Chronology</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
</body>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want that the header take the 100% of the screen?, I ask because of this `header {  height: 100%;}`

Comment: What I want to do is create something like this: http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-grayscale/

Comment: As you can see the header when viewed looks to be covering the whole page and then when you scroll down, other elements appear!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `height: 100%` to `html, body`, remove `position: absolute` from `header` and set `top: 100%` to  `.site-nav` like this:

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  line-height: 1;
}

html, body{ /*added*/
    height: 100%;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

q, blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Fragment;
  src: url("../fonts/Fragmentcore.otf");
}
.site-nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #fff;
  width: 12%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 100%; /*added*/
    
}
.site-nav li {
  margin: 0.97em 0.8em 0 0.8em;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
.site-nav a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Fragment';
  font-weight: bold;
}
.site-nav li:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
.site-nav li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .site-nav {
    left: 85px;
    width: 19%;
  }
}

header {
  /*position: absolute;*/ /*removed*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: white;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*@media screen and (min-width: $size-small){
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
  }*/
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  font-family: 'Fragment';
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 42px;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="header-container"></div>
    </header>

    <section id="content">
        <nav class="site-nav">
            <h1>Chronology</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

Anyway is even better removing the `position: absolute` from `.site-nav` and let it follow the flow of the document, I comment the change in the css. I really recommend you this:

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
  line-height: 1;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

q, blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Fragment;
  src: url("../fonts/Fragmentcore.otf");
}
.site-nav {
  /*position: absolute;*/  /*removed*/
  /*left: 100px;*/  /*removed*/
  /*width: 12%;*/
  display: inline-block; /*added*/
  margin-left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  top: 100%; /*added*/
    
}
.site-nav li {
  margin: 0.97em 0.8em 0 0.8em;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
.site-nav a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Fragment';
  font-weight: bold;
}
.site-nav li:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
.site-nav li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .site-nav {
    margin-left: 85px;
  }
}

header {
  /*position: absolute;*/ /*removed*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: white;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*@media screen and (min-width: $size-small){
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
  }*/
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  font-family: 'Fragment';
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 42px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="header-container"></div>
    </header>

    <section id="content">
        <nav class="site-nav">
            <h1>Chronology</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

Comment: @bgm Let me know if this is the behavior that you want: the `header `occupy the 100% of the screen, the `.content` including the `.site-nav` is right under the `header`